# Apache shiro - how do I know that caching is working for authorization?

Tags: tomcat, ehcache, shiro

I am using Apache Shiro in my Tomcat and I want to enable caching of authorization through EhCache.

What I've done is adding these two lines in shiro.ini:

```
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
```

and copied ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar in my WEB-INF/lib directory. For the authorization, I have implemented a custom Realm that reads the permissions from a MySQL Databaase. So I want to enable the cache in order to reduce as much as possible the queries to the database... I have to mention that I am not familiar with EhCache and I only want to enable caching of the authorization!

If I've understood the Shiro documentation correctly, the above are enough to enable the caching - however I am not seeing that :(

Tomcat Starts without exceptions and, in a test JSP I am using authorization works ok at first. After if I make a change to the permissions of the database I see that the test JSP is immediately aware of the change! I was expecting that the test JSP would return the values from the cache... Can you tell me what could be wrong ? Also, is there a way to find out if EhCache is actually called and how it behaves (if logging needs to be enabled I'd be grateful if you gave me detailed information because I am not very familiar with that).

**Update:** I also have to mention that I added the line

```
System.out.println("Caching is enabled " + isCachingEnabled() );
```

in the initialization of my custom realm and I get true!

TIA,

Serafeim

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't know Shiro, and I don't know Tomcat well, but I have a fair understanding of EHCache.  I know that the API supports cache updates.  Depending on how Shiro uses EHCache, it may update the cached information when ever it changes.  Your JSP showing it updated does not prove that the cache is or isn't working.

In programming, it is fairly easy to insert code to capture statistics for EHCache, but I'm not sure how you would when it is integrated in this manner.  EHCache has built-in logging for when enclosing applications are set to a high logging level, but I've had trouble making it work in 2.5.1.  Logging settings for EHCache are described here:  http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/logging, but I don't know how you would set Shiro to output the messages.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use jconsole to watch the JMX statistics of EHCache.

1. Start jconsole
2. Open the MBeans tab
3. On the left-hand side, open "net.sf.ehcache" tree.
4. Navigate to net.sf.ehcache/CacheStatistics/[your cache name, defaults to net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@some_id]
5. Find your cache by name, open the tree and choose "Attributes"

Now, you can look at the attributes of your cache. Play with your app and watch whether the "CacheHits" and "ObjectCount" variables change as they should. ObjectCount is all the items that ehcache has cached at any given time; CacheHits shows you whether those items are actually being used.

You can also do this remotely, but that gets a bit hairy - you'll need to tunnel JConsole through a SOCKS proxy. This article details the steps to do that: http://simplygenius.com/2010/08/jconsole-via-socks-ssh-tunnel.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a step-through debugger, try putting a breakpoint at subject.login() ie:

```
Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(userName, password);
subject.login(token);
```

That should step you through: org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.java
org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.java

You will see attempts to access the cache in AuthenticatingRealm.java

Good luck!